# How to create multi dimension array in php for followingg input

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

i have input array format and i convert into the multi dimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [third_party_id] => 2
            [third_party_name] => aardvarkg
            [parameter_id] => 221
            [parameter_name] => new2
            [param_value] => 1
            [sub_param_name] => new2_new2
            [sub_param_value] => 1_1
            [sub_bidder_id] => 72
        )
          [1] => Array
        (
            [third_party_id] => 2
            [third_party_name] => aardvarkg
            [parameter_id] => 222
            [parameter_name] => new
            [param_value] => 1
            [sub_param_name] => new
            [sub_param_value] => 1
            [sub_bidder_id] => 74
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [third_party_id] => 3
            [third_party_name] => aard
            [parameter_id] => 221
            [parameter_name] => new2
            [param_value] => 3
            [sub_param_name] => new2
            [sub_param_value] => th
            [sub_bidder_id] => 78
        )
)
```

i need output is multidimensional array format.parent and child array.

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [third_party_id] => 2
            [third_party_name] => aardvarkg
            [param]                =>[parameter_id] => 221
                                  [parameter_name] => new2
                                  [param_value] => 1
                                  [subparam]           => [sub_param_name] => new2_new2
                                                   [sub_param_value] => 1_1
                                                    [sub_bidder_id] => 72
        )
```

i need the output answer above array format..any helping hands will be appericiated

Answer (score 2):

Pass your Two Dimensional array as below

```
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$array)
{ 
$i = 1;
    foreach($array as $names=>$values)
    {
    if($i<=2)
    {
    $multidimension[$key][$names] = $values; 
    }
    if($i>=3 && $i<=5)
    {
        $multidimension[$key]['param'][$names] = $values; 
    }
    if($i>5)
    {
        $multidimension[$key]['param']['subparam'][$names] = $values; 
    }
    $i++;
    }
}

print_r($multidimension); //expected array output
```

Comment: [0] => Array
        (
            [third_party_id] => 2
            [third_party_name] => aardvarkg
            [param]                => Array([parameter_id] => 221
                                  [parameter_name] => new2
                                  [param_value] => 1
                                  [subparam]           => [sub_param_name] => new2_new2
                                                   [sub_param_value] => 1_1
                                                    [sub_bidder_id] => 72
        )

Comment: is this what you got?

Comment: i got multiple third party again and again.i need only one third party id then all values under the inner array

Comment: in this input array i have two third party id but it loops five times.i need only two array..

Comment: `[third_party_id] => 3` dont you need this?

Comment: i need [third_party_id] => 3 and [third_party_id] => 3....but i output array is   [0] => [third_party_id] => 2 is one time under sub array  value only differ [0]=>[parameter_id] => 221and [1]=>[parameter_id] => 222

Comment: How about `print_r($multidimension[0]);`

Comment: Array
(
    [third_party_id] => 2
    [third_party_name] => aardvarkg
    [param] => Array
        (
            [parameter_id] => 221
            [parameter_name] => new2
            [param_value] => 1
            [subparam] => Array
                (
                    [sub_param_name] => new2_new2
                    [sub_param_value] => 1_1
                    [sub_bidder_id] => 72
                )

        )

)

Comment: but i need Array
(
    [third_party_id] => 2
    [third_party_name] => aardvarkg
    [param] => Array
        (
           [0]=> Array(
                [parameter_id] => 221
            [parameter_name] => new2
            [param_value] => 1
)
 [1]=> Array(
            [parameter_id] => 221
            [parameter_name] => new2
            [param_value] => 1
)
            [subparam] => Array
                (
                    [sub_param_name] => new2_new2
                    [sub_param_value] => 1_1
                    [sub_bidder_id] => 72
                )
        ))

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

```
$a = array
(
    array
        (
           "third_party_id" => 2,
            "third_party_name" => 'aardvarkg',
            "parameter_id" => 221,
            "parameter_name" => 'new2',

              "param" =>  array(
        "param_value" => 1),
              "sub_param" => array(
        "sub_param_name" => 'new2_new2',
        "sub_param_value" => '1_1',
        "sub_bidder_id" => 72)
    )

);
  print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map and array_slice, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/846875).

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
  $temp = array_slice($v, 0, 2);
  $temp['param'] = array_slice($v, 2, 3);
  $temp['param']['subparam'] = array_slice($v, 5);
  return $temp;
}, $arr);
```